# PHP triggering mail functions at a set time and date

Tags: php, datetime, time, sendmail, gmt

I want to check the stock level every day at a certain time (say 11pm GMT) and email a list of items that are low on stock to the admin. I have managed to get the mailing function working but I am struggling to limit the checks to once a day (right now it sends an email to the admin email every time the page loads)

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You will need to put your script in a separate file and run once per day with a cron job

Comment: What technology stack are you using? If LAMP as @Fabio mentions Cron will be your solution

Comment: what fabio said would be the best way to go you wont have to load any page and the cron job will be executed in a set interval but you will have to ask your server admin to do that

Comment: very few set ups require asking "server admin" to set up a cron job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just need to put your script in a separate file and run once per day with a `cron job`

You might want to read more about cron jobs in this post [How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: I followed the instructions as provided in the link but I did not receive an email. It might be because the time zone of the server is not GMT. Still not sure if it worked 100% :(

Comment: Cron works with server time, so set the time for it according to server time, also check logs to see if you have any problems with the script.

Comment: Its fine!! it's working!! I got the url wrong lol. Silly mistake. Thanks for your link :)

Answer (score 1):

In case that impossible to run a cron job, you can save last mail time in DB or file and check timeout on page load.